# Why the items I add to my ObservableList are only accessible from the function they are declared

Tags: java, javafx

## Context

I just started to learn JavaFX so I'm developing a program to discover it. The program I'm on needs a array, so I used ObservableList. But here is the problem, the items I add to the list are only accessible from the function itself.

Here is the situation :

```
package fr.cartes;

import fr.cartes.model.MapModel;
import fr.cartes.view.ListMapsController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;

    private ObservableList<MapModel> maps = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("/!\\ Explorateur /!\\");
        this.primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        initializationOfProgram();
    }

    public void initializationOfProgram(){
        initializeListMaps();

        maps.add(new MapModel("Les Etats-Unis d'Amérique", "EU.jpg"));
        maps.add(new MapModel("La France d'aujourdh'ui", "FR.jpg"));

        for(MapModel mapModel : maps){
          System.out.println(mapModel.getMapName());
        }

    }

    public void initializeListMaps(){
        for(MapModel map : maps){
            System.out.println(map.getMapName());
        }
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/ListMaps.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            ListMapsController controller = new ListMapsController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
            controller.loadMapsOnListView(maps);
        }catch(IOException exception){exception.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public ObservableList<MapModel> getMapsLists(){
        return maps;
    }
}
```

For example, if I put a **println()** test in the **initializationOfProgram()**, I will have *"Les Etats-Unis d'Amérique"* and *"La France d'aujourd'hui"* written on the console, but if I do this **println()** test in **initializeListMaps()**, it won't display anything.
Am I missing something obvious here ? Can you help me ?

Comment: Order matters. What order do you call methods and add things to the map? Step through the program in your mind and you'll see.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what I've been doing those last three hours :'( Logically, the program starts with the start() function. I've being trying many things, but none work. The thing that is weird is that if I declare my two items on start(), I won't be able to access them in initializationOfProgram(), which the function called just after it.

Comment: Look at the `initializationOfProgram()` method and see for yourself what happens first: the elements being added to the list or the `initializeListMaps()` being called...

Comment: As an aside (this is something that will be an issue once you fix the current one): You are creating a new controller instance and connecting the application instance to it. That instance of the controller has nothing to do with the UI. You need to get the controller instance from the FXMLLoader.

Comment: Thanks everybody, it know works ! I guess I shouldn't have stuck to my computer so long... I missed a lot of dummy mistakes.